# find dynamic values from url as per regular expression defined

Tags: python, regex

I am having two inputs for my task

```
>>> uri = u'/shop/amazonwow/getstates/1'
>>> uri_regex = u'/shop/(?P<shopid>.+)$/getstates/(?P<countryid>.+)$/'
```

Here `uri` is the request url and also i am passing a uri pattern(uri_regex) with it.
I need to fetch all dynamic data from uri .We will decide which data is dynamic as per our uri_regex .
**Example :** Here uri_regex has shopid , countryid as regular expression pattern  and url is having values `amazonwow , 1 at same indexes.

My output will be like :

```
out = {'shopid': 'amazonwow', 'countryid' :1,}
```

My Try :

```
>>> uri_list = uri.split('/')
[u'', u'shop', u'amazonwow', u'getstates', u'1']
>>> regex = uri_regex.split('/')
>>> regex
    [u'', u'shop', u'(?P<shopid>.+)$', u'getstates', u'(?P<countryid>.+)$']
>>> out = {}
>>> for i in range(len(regex)):
    if regex[i].startswith('(?') & regex[i].endswith(')$'):
                key = regex[i][regex[i].find("<")+1:regex[i].find(">")]
        out[key] = uri_list[i]


>>> print out
{u'shopid': u'amazonwow', u'countryid': u'1'}
>>>
```

**Note :** i tried this but i do not think it is proper solution to above problem. Please guide me if you guys have much better way.

Comment: First point: your regexp is wrong - the `$` symbol has a special meaning in regexp syntax. Second point: what's wrong with Python's `re` module (part of the stdlib...) ?

Comment: Thanks for feedback .. i know that's y i am looking for better solution may be by using re module .

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
uri = u'/shop/amazonwow/getstates/1'
pattern = re.compile(u'shop/(.+)/getstates/(.+)')
if pattern.search(uri):
    out['shopid'] = pattern.search(uri).groups()[0]
    out['countryid'] = pattern.search(uri).groups()[1]
```

Output:

`out = {'countryid': '1', 'shopid': 'amazonwow'}`

Comment: shopid , countryid . these values are dynamic depends on url we are passing . values can be bankid , customerid anything we are passing into url

Comment: What about url's, how they can look like? `Values` you create out of strings yourself in process of making dict pairs.

Comment: uri and uri_regex can be anything . when i am fetching uri and uri_regex values into my views.py i am getting only values of both of them .

Comment: For example, if we have `shop` in `uri`, we know that we need to extract string after `shop/` until to, but not including next `/` and create dict key `shopid` which will hold value from the extracted regex search match. Same goes for if we have `getstates` in `uri`, we will extract value after `/` and assign it to value in dict. But if `uri` can be literally _anything_ I don't see a way for writing regex that will match, and remember _anything_ as a group.

Comment: uri_regex can have anything into it . they can have any value if they have any regular expression pattern into it we will just simply fetch values from uri at same index.  you can see my code i am not providing there value like shopid , country id because there we can have anything ...

Answer (score 0):

My Try:

```
def fetch_uri_variables(uri, uri_regex): 
    """
    function to fetch dynamic variables passed in uri as per 
    regular expression defined into uri_regex
    """
    out, uri_list, uri_regex = {}, uri.split('/'), uri_regex.split('/')
    for pattern in range(len(uri_regex)):
         if re.search('^(\(\?)(.*)(\)\$)$', uri_regex[pattern]):
             out[re.search('\<(.*)\>', uri_regex[pattern]).group(1)] = \
                uri_list[pattern]
    return out

>>> uri
u'/testing/shop/amazonwow/getstates/1'
>>> uri_regex
u'/(?P<test>.+)$/shop/(?P<shopid>.+)$/getstates/(?P<countryid>.+)$/'
>>> fetch_uri_variables(uri, uri_regex)
{u'test': u'testing', u'countryid': u'1', u'shopid': u'amazonwow'}
>>>
```